How to use XSSFFormulaEvaluator to evaluate formula?
I need to use POI to handle a Excel .xlsx file in Java.
There is SUM formula in my Excel template. (e.g. =SUM(C4:C7))
In the beginning, I use a existed method in our program, but it end in line 3 without exception throw and does not return outputStream.
I have set breakpoints to observe. It skiped all lines after running the first breakpoint.
public ByteArrayOutputStream export() throws Exception {
    try {
        XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);  //Line 3, first breakpoint
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        this.workbook.write(outputStream);
        return outputStream;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //second breakpoint
        throw new OtherException(e);
    }
}

There is no error or exception message on IDE console. Only ognl.MethodFailedException is thrown. 'Method "xxx" failed for object' is shown on browser.
It can run normally if I toggle comment on line 3. Changing the SUM formula to just use plus sign also can run normally. (e.g. =C4+C5+C6+C7)
I changed all cells' type to numeric which involve in SUM formula but the same problem still happen.
Although I can evaluate the formula by other ways, I still want to know the reason of XSSFFormulaEvaluator fail.
Below is my environment.
IDE: Red Hat Developer Studio
JRE: Java-1.8
Server: JBoss Version 7.2.0.GA
POI Version: 4.0.1

provide the stacktrace

also poi 4.0.1 was released in 2018 - could you try poi 5.3.0 (recently released)?

Sorry I don't know how to print the stacktrace. I tried to add a line e.printStackTrace(); in catch and toggle breakpoint on this line and line 3 which is XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);.
The IDE stopped at line 3 but did not stop at e.printStackTrace();. ognl.MethodFailedException is shown on the browser.
Due to my department policy, I cannot try poi 5.3.0.

Please [edit] your question to show your revised approach and results. Include a [mre] that reproduces the problem. This might allow others still using that version to verify the result.
